# What exactly is the "size" of a function in a symbol table?

Tags: c

when you are given the symbol size in bytes of a function in a symbol table of an ELF file what does this exactly mean and how does this connect to the range of execution of a function?

Answer (score 2):

It's purely the difference between the byte address one past the end of the machine code comprising the function and the byte address of the first byte of the function, and it's largely useless. While size matters for data (due to the possibility of copy relocations), incorrect/meaningless values in the size field for function symbols should not cause any problem, and it's probably a bad idea to rely on the values except for debugging or reverse engineering purposes.